# Is there anyway to use fit_generator() method with KerasRegressor wrapper?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, lstm, gridsearchcv

I am trying to tune hyper-parameters for my LSTM model using GridSearchCV but have used TimeseriesGenerator from keras.preprocessing.sequence. How do I modify the KerasRegressor wrapper to accommodate fit_generator() instead of the fit() method?

```
def create_model(layer1=50): 
    lstm_model = Sequential()
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(layer1, input_shape=(10,11)))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(11, activation='tanh'))
    lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
    return lstm_model

model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, epochs=5, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

layer1 = [40,50]
param_grid = dict(layer1=layer1)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit(X, y)
```

But how do I use KerasRegressor with a generator like

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
train_data_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(X, y,length=10,batch_size=100)
```